# java session in servlet the same as sessionstorage in javascript

Tags: javascript, java, jquery

I have a servlet which I call the following:

```
request.getSession().setAttribute("name", nameObj);
```

Can I access it from the following page using

```
console.log('IH HERE' + sessionStorage.getItem('name') );
```

It doesn't seem to work.  Either js or jquery solution would be nice.

Thanks,

Scott

Comment: You can read java session from cookies but not from sessionstorage

Answer (score 0):

This won't work, for two reasons:

1. `sessionStorage` is client-side only; it's not sent to the server via HTTP requests and the server can't write it without talking to the client.
2. `request.getSession()` is server-side only, with a session ID stored in a cookie but nothing else stored in a client-accessible format.

You'll have to use cookies if you want to achieve this effect (read / write by both) or loop over the session and provide it all in the page somewhere (read only by client).